Analyzing Cumulative Distribution Functions in Sampling Without Replacement vs. With Replacement
Originally asked on MATHEMATICS.
I am studying a population of $N$ bits, comprising $K$ ones and $N-K$ zeros. For sampling $n$ bits without replacement, the situation conforms to a hypergeometric distribution. The sum of these $n$ bits, $S_n$, yields a mean of $n\frac{K}{N}$ and a variance of $n \frac{K}{N} \frac{N-K}{N} \frac{N-n}{N-1}$. Conversely, sampling $n'$ bits with replacement aligns with a binomial distribution, with the sum $S_{n'}$ having a mean of $n'\frac{K}{N}$ and a variance of $n' \frac{K}{N} \frac{N-K}{N}$.
For my analysis, I plotted the cumulative distribution functions (CDFs) for the normalized sums $\frac{S_n}{n}$ and $\frac{S_{n'}}{n'}$, considering values of $n'$ within the range $\left[n,\lfloor n\frac{N-1}{N-n}\rfloor\right]$. I observed that for normalized sums exceeding $\frac{K}{N}$, the binomial CDF consistently lies below the hypergeometric CDF. The trend is longer followed for $n'>n\frac{N-1}{N-n}$.
If $X$ is a hypergeometric distribution with n draws without replacement from a population of size $N$ with $K$ successes and $Y$ is a binomial distribution $B(n',K/N)$, then what is the maximum $n'$ for which $F_Y(f n')\leq F_X(f  n)$ for $f\geq K/N$?.
I suppose that the maximum $n'= \lfloor n\frac{N-1}{N-n}\rfloor$.
Heres an animation for $\frac{K}{N}=0.5$, with $N=50$ where the number of binomial trials is fixed at $n'=n\frac{N-1}{N-n}=21$ and number of hypergeometric trials is fixed at $n=15$. The portion marked green is the region where the normalized sums are greater than $p=\frac{K}{N}$. In this region the binomial CDF is below the hypergeometric CDF.

I'm curious if this relationship between the distributions' CDFs is a recognized phenomenon. It is noted that the variance of the normalised hypergeometric distribution is lower than that of the binomial distribution if $n'<n\frac{N-1}{N-n}$. Maybe this is relevant somehow? Does anyone know of relevant research articles on this topic?
Here’s the Mathematica code used for generating these plots, adjustable for different $p=K/N$ values:
Manipulate[Nx = 10^2;
 n = 30;
 x = p Nx;
 ListPlot[{Table[{k/Floor[binomialtrials], 
     CDF[BinomialDistribution[Floor[binomialtrials], p], k]}, {k, 1, 
     Floor[binomialtrials]}], 
   Table[{k/n, 
     CDF[HypergeometricDistribution[n, Floor[x], Nx], k]}, {k, 1, 
     n}]}, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> {"bin", "hype"}, 
  Epilog -> {RGBColor[0, 1, 0, 0.25], Rectangle[{p, 0}, {1, 1}], Red, 
    Line[{{p, 0}, {p, 1}}]}], {binomialtrials, n, n (Nx - 1)/(Nx - n),
   1}, {p, 10^-2, 1}]


Does anyone have insights or references which might explain this pattern?

Since you describe several properties and provide several distinct comparisons of Binomial and Hypergeometric distributions, please state explicitly what you mean by "this characteristic relationship."

I have added such a statement

Here is perhaps a hint. Random sampling without replacement yields the permutations of some definite proportion of ones and zeros. Sampling with replacement includes, in addition to the aforementioned definite proportion, all other proportions including having all ones or all zeros, iff there is at least a single 1 and a single 0 in the original sequence. Since sampling with replacement can, with low probability, be a permutation the minimum difference is none.
